# Add Subpanel? trying to identify what is possible with existing panel (no space left)

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, kitchens

I am looking at a small kitchen renovation and **would like to understand what it would take to bring everything up to code for the kitchen(NEC2017)**.
My current panel (square D) is original from the mid 80s and seems to be a mess. We have one particular circuit that is overloaded (11). Some of the breakers dont make sense to me (very much a newbie), such as the A/C and why there is 1 breakers for the washer/dryer plus one for an unused outlet, or the hell they go a microwave, what I think is 240V baseboard heater (might need to re-confirm that one) and a bunch of lights/outlet on a 15A breaker. Would a subpanel be an option here? or something else given everything a kitchen would require now?

Here is what I believe I need for the new kitchen:
2x20A for outlets,1x50A for range,1x20A for fridge,1x15A for diswasher,1x15A for lights, 1x20A for microwave, 1x??A for beverage fridge, 1x?? for toekick electric heater.

Below are pictures of the current panel. The open picture is from before we added added 2 circuits (one for the new fridge, one for a beverage cooler+outlet)

- Breaker 1: 20A: outlet for the upstairs washer/dryer (currently switched off?)
- Breaker 2+4: 20A, 240V Baseboard Heaters Kitchen and Dining room
- Breaker 3: 20A Kitchen outlets
- Breaker 5: 20A currently switched off
- Breaker 6+8:20A 240V Bedroom 2 baseboard heater
- Breaker 7: 15A Dishwasher
- Breaker 9: 15A 1 kitchen outlet and switched outlet (used to have fridge and disposal)
- Breaker 10+12: 20A, 240V Baseboard heaters: living room and primary bedroom
- **Breaker 11: 15A Kitchen and Dining Lights, Living+ Primary bedroom Outlets, Microwave, *baseboard heaters living room(to be confirmed)***
- Breaker 13: 15A lights: Hallway, primary bedroom, closet; 2nd bedroom outlets, smoke detector
- Breaker 14+16: 30A,240V Washer and Dryer (eletric)
- Breaker 15, 15A Lights: foyer, bathrooms(x2), stairwell, closet; Outlets: bathrooms (x2), primary bedroom, 2nd bedroom, living room, foyer. Doorbell
- Breaker 17+19: 15A, A/C blower
- Breaker 18: 20A, wine cooler plus outlet
- Breaker 20:15A, fridge
- Breaker 21-23: 40A, A/C thermostat
- Breaker 22+24: 40A, 240V electric range

Apparently power from 7 runs through 3/9, 11 passes through 2/9? (unsure what that means just adding from notes)
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish on the electrical side of this kitchen remodel? Adding more small appliance circuits for kitchen outlets? Switching out the range? Simply rationalizing unused stuff? Also, are you going to be putting in upgraded homeruns to the panel as part of this, and what's the deal with all the baseboard heaters?

Comment: well #1 is being able to get permitted for the reno, which apparently requires bringing everything to nec2017. Baseboard heating is the source of heating so we have a few. We have a full panel with seemingly no room, the microwave keeps tripping if we use the dehumidifer upstairs (same circuit), I am adding countertop outlets to meet code  but it is for location convenience not because I am running out. so if I can get stuff right for the kitchen while fixing some of my issues, it may be worthwhile. I am afraid I am not sure what upgraded homeruns are..

Comment: What I mean by "upgraded homeurns" would be pulling 12AWG for some circuits to replace the existing 14AWG wiring

Comment: well some of the walls will be open so that may be an option? I am not against it, not sure what it would entail. the panel is in the staircase in the middle of the room, under stairs and we have concrete slab flooring. so could be complicated.

Comment: Weird. Why is the problem circuit blue?  Do you have a significant amount of conduit in this installation?  Also is there a sticker anywhere indicating the "box number" of this panel? Where is the main breaker?

Comment: Is red an optional color for hot wires, and if so, are all of these red wires running in conduit or something?

Comment: My understanding is that it is all or a lot of conduit since that is supposed to be code here? I definitely know there is some in the kitchen on the exterior wall. The main breaker is likely in the garage, this is a Multi family building with steel frame, access to main panels is in the common area. No idea abou the blue wire but with the very limited stuff I did, the wiring colors seems to have little meaning for whoever did the install originally,  posting another pic of the box with info, maybe that would help.

Comment: @Huesmann hot colors (in the USA/Canada system) are literally any colors other than white, gray, green or green striped with yellow. White and gray include other colors with 3 continuous stripes of gray or white (useful for keeping track of what neutral goes with what hot in a conduit system.) Black red blue orange yellow brown purple pink are all valid hot colors.

Comment: It would be _very_ helpful if you told us where "here" is. Some locations (NYC & Chicago, for example) _require_ conduit to reduce the likelihood and damage from an electrical fire, while most locales do not _require_ conduit, but it's always an option.

Comment: Sorry, i should have added location. In IL, greater Chicago area.

Comment: That explains the conduit at least -- good news is that since it is a conduit job in all likelihood, swapping the existing 14AWG wires for 12AWG is no big deal, and you may also be able to pull additional circuits into the existing conduits while you're at it depending on the amount of space available in them

Comment: Does pulling new wire usually require opening the wall? would it be pulling wires from the meter? I am struggling to understand the very basics of what is possible here. If the panel is not far from the kitchen, and most of the wiring is conduit, what is exactly needed to get a kitchen with the all the electrical requirements under nec2017? This may sound like a super basic question but I am trying to understand what I dealing with.

Comment: If you use the same conduit, I believe you can just use your old 14ga wire to pull your new 12ga wire.